# Find the dimension of the intersection and sum of two vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to solve the following exercise:

In the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ , consider the subspace V given by the solutions of the system
$\begin{cases}
x+2y+z=0\\
-x-y+3t = 0
\end{cases}$

and the subspace $W$ generated by the vectors:

$w_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 2\\0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $w_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 3\\-2\\-2\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Compute $\dim (W\cap W)$ and $\dim (V + W)$.

If I compute the dimension of $V\cap W$ first, by writing $W$ as a system of equations, I find $\dim (V\cap W) = 1$, and by Grassmann's formula I can conclude that $\dim (V + W) = 3$.

If I try to do the opposite, finding a base of $V+W$ first, I can't manage to get to the same result. I always get four linearly independent vectors, which would imply the intersection of the two subspaces is empty.

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing in the reasoning you describe seems flawed, so it must be your computations. I do not have the time nor the motivation for re-doing them, but my advice would be : re-do them (without looking at your first draft) and, at each step, check everyting that can be checked (for instance, do the vectors supposed to satisfy an equation really do so ? If you find linearly independant vectors, can you check that using the determinant ? etc.). You should be able to get to the same result using both methods. Good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first subspace $U$ is given by $\begin{cases}x+2y+z=0\\-x-y+3t=0 \end{cases}$, so $x=-2y-z$ and $t=\dfrac{x}{3}+\dfrac{y}{3}=-\dfrac{y}{3}-\dfrac{z}{3}$.
This shows that we have a vector subspace of dimension two given by:
$$U=\langle u_1,u_2\rangle=\langle\begin{pmatrix}-6\\3\\0\\-1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-3\\0\\3\\-1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle.$$
Then we have the second subspace $W$ generated by $w_1=\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $w_2=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-2\\-2\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. If we want to find the dimension of the subspace $U+W$ we have to study the number of linearly independent vectors:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-6&-3&2&3\\3&0&0&-2\\0&3&1&-2\\-1&-1&1&0 \end{pmatrix}\sim \begin{pmatrix}-6&-3&2&3\\0&-2&2&-1\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\implies \text{dim}(U+W)=3$$
hence it's generated by the three vectors $u_1,u_2$ and $w_1$.
At this point we know that $\text{dim}(U\cap W)=2+2-3=1$ and it's easy to see that the vector $(5,-2,-1,1)^T\in U\cap W$ (solving the system $\alpha u_1+\beta u_2=\gamma w_1+\delta w_2$)